# Is checking subsequent REST API request with token secure enough?

Tags: rest, security

In my REST API, user will log in with their username and password for the first time.

When they logged in successfully, we will response with the following format.

```
{
  "token": "0c7f8b870675bc61d92baeef1e274c2d31343736393530373230",
  "expire_on": "2016-11-19T18:05:20+0000",
  "user_id": 30,
  "user": {...}
}
```

On the subsequent to the REST API, we will just send `token` in the header to verify the user. `token` is `52` letters long.

Is it secure enough?

Should I send both `token` and `user_id` to verify to secure more?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how do you generate your token.
If someone can guess how they are generated then it can create a fake one.
If this is a random string that is saved on your server and for each request you check the existence in your server then you are safe.
The best current solution for stateless token is JWT. Take a look at https://jwt.io/

Answer (score 0):

Did you implement your authentication layer? I would suggest having a look at the Oauth2 specification and you are interested in the section when the grant_type is password. If you follow it, it will be safe to return just the access token:

> [5.1.  Successful Response](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-5.1)
>
> The authorization server issues an access token and optional
> refresh    token, and constructs the response by adding the following
> parameters    to the entity-body of the HTTP response with a 200 (OK)
> status code:
>
> access_token
> REQUIRED.  The access token issued by the authorization server.
>
> token_type
> REQUIRED.  The type of the token issued as described in
> Section 7.1.  Value is case insensitive.
>
> expires_in
> RECOMMENDED.  The lifetime in seconds of the access token.  For
> example, the value "3600" denotes that the access token will
> expire in one hour from the time the response was generated.
> If omitted, the authorization server SHOULD provide the
> expiration time via other means or document the default value

.

Comment: Should I use Oauth for authenticating my own client and my own server? I thought OAuth is to authenticate cross apps log-in?

Comment: @moeseth Oauth2 provides different grant_types. The grant_type that the cross-apps are using is called 'authorization'. The oauth2 specification mentions the 'password' grant_type as well which can be used to exchange a username and password for an access token directly. Just be a bit careful how you use it if you already have an oauth server in place. You can have a look here for more info: http://oauthlib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/oauth2/grants/password.html and here https://aaronparecki.com/2012/07/29/2/oauth2-simplified

Comment: @moeseth This resource can be helpful as well: https://apigility.org/documentation/auth/authentication-oauth2 under Username and password access section

Comment: Thanks for your help Svabael.